# How to extract a prefix given a suffix in a DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

```
pc --> [ta] -> [tb] -> [tc] .
```

If I have `tc` , how do I get `[ta,tb]` put into a variable?

If I have the tail end of a list defined in a definite clause, how do I get the preceeding elements as a list of unknown length?

I am hoping that approach can be extended to a case where the prefix of a string known at the time of a query be extracted with the suffix removed.

For example, given "sweetness", use a DCG describing the suffix "ness" to bind "sweet" to a variable.

Do not only use 'append'.

The following examples are not part of the question, they are information for other people learning definite clauses up to this stage of complexity.

```
pa --> [ta] .
```

Can test with

```
phrase(pa,[ta]) .
```

To fill variable with match, do

```
phrase(ptrn,Variable) .

pb --> [ta] -> [tb] .
```

The head element can be gotten with

```
phrase(pb,[Head|[tb]]) .
```

Comment: Why are you using `(->)/2` it seems  that `(',')/2` is what you rather intend.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SWI-Prolog, from [`library(dcg_basics)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl), there is `string//1` non-terminal that should work the way you want:

```
?- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
...

?- phrase((string(L), [pc]), [pa,pb,pc]).
L = [pa, pb] ;
false.
```

the implementation is quite simple:

```
string([]) -->
    [].
string([H|T]) -->
    [H],
    string(T).
```

OT: you're using `->//2` as a sequence, and albeit it should work for your simple case, be aware it really introduces the if/then/else construct.